# inserting an ajax response into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

First time AJAX attempt.....
I am attempting to update a  based on a selection made with a button.

I am currently just alerting the ID back, as that is all I can figure out what to do.

Is it possible to put the file my_page.php into the div with class "populated_info"?
Then when I press a different button, the page will function will run again, and populate the div with the new result.  I have the my_page.php already built and running based on the ID, just can't get it to render in the correct place.

HTML:

```
    <form name="gen_info">
<div class="body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <table width="100%" class="border_yes">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Last Name, First Name
                    </td>
                </tr>
        <?php
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM general_info");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $CURRENT_ID = $row['ID'];
                    $firstName = $row['firstName'];
                    $lastName = $row['lastName'];
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default custom" onclick="function1('<?php echo $CURRENT_ID;?>')"><?php echo $lastName.', '.$firstName; ?></button> 
                            <!-- button that will run the function -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
        <?php       
}
        ?>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 populated_info"> <!-- WHERE I WOULD LIKE THE UPDATED INFORMATION -->

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

AJAX:

```
<script>
function function1(ID) {
$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "functions/my_page.php",
  data: "ID="+ID,
  success: function(resp){
    alert(resp); //how to get this to put the page back into the right spot?
  },  
  error: function(e){  
  alert('Error: ' + e);  
  }
 });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your approach:**

With regards to your button, I'd suggest separating the inline Javascript handler to keep your HTML and Javascript separate. I'll use a custom data attribute to store the ID here:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default custom mybutton" data-id="<?php echo $CURRENT_ID;?>">
    <?php echo $lastName . ', ' . $firstName; ?>
</button>
```

Then jQuery:

```
$('.mybutton').click(function() {
    var ID = $(this).data('id');
    function1(ID);
});
```

**Your AJAX request:**

You can shorten that whole function and use [`$.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to get the data into your div:

```
function function1(ID) {
    // Get the output of functions/my_page.php, passing ID as parameter, and
    // replace the contents of .populated_info with it
    $('.populated_info').load('functions/my_page.php', { ID: ID });
}
```

Doesn't look like you need a callback function here, but if you do you can put it in after the data parameter. A useful application of a callback here might be for your error handler. [See here](http://api.jquery.com/load/#example-1) how to implement one.

An an aside, if you're just getting data, you should probably be using the GET HTTP method instead of POST.

Answer (score 0):

if you successfully get the response from the server just `replace alert(resp)` with `$('.populated_info').html(resp);`

```
<script>
    function function1(ID) {
    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "functions/my_page.php",
      data: "ID="+ID,
      success: function(resp){
        $('.populated_info').html(resp);
      },  
      error: function(e){  
      alert('Error: ' + e);  
      }
     });
    }
    </script>
```